# Preserving line breaks with React-Admin / Material UI's Textfields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I'm using React-Admin and have a field in my database that contains linebreaks (\n). When I output this on a page like this:

`<TextField source="extra_details" />`

The linebreaks are ignored and everything runs together. How can I make the linebreaks show properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom `TextField` with `pre-wrap` style by default:

```js
import { FC } from "react";
import { TextField as BaseTextField, TextFieldProps } from "react-admin";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  textContent: {
    whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"
  },
});

export const TextField: FC<TextFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <BaseTextField
    className={classes.textContent}
    {...props}
  />
}
TextField.defaultProps = {
  addLabel: true,
}
```

Then use it as you use the vendor `TextField`.

Please note the `addLabel` option: You need it to keep the label being shown with a custom component.

You can have more details and sample here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#styling-fields

Answer (score 1):

Styles may help...

```js
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  displayLinebreakAndTab: {whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" },
};

const SomeText = withStyles(styles)(({classes, ...props}) => (
  <TextField
    className={classes.displayLinebreakAndTab}
    {...props}
  />
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread very helpful. https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2403

The TextField component passes all its props to the underlying Typography component. So you can do:

`<TextField component="pre" />`

Comment: Using component="pre" in a TextField within a list breaks the heading of the React-Admin list - the "Add Filter" and "Export" buttons no longer appear.Use useStyles and associate whitespace: Pre-wrap to the field per Soullivaneuh's recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

What about `<RichTextField />`?

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#richtextfield

Or you could always create your own TextField component.